# How can I make my Python run ANSI encoded files without converting to UTF-8?

Tags: python, utf-8, ansi

I have script I can trying to run and I get this error

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xf3'
```

How can I still go ahead to run the script or make my computer default encoding ANSI?

I can't edit the script.

Comment: What do you mean by _I cant edit the script_? Don't you have an editor?

Comment: @Armali the script was made for me and the writer locked the code or something, so it shows just scribbles when i open it

Comment: If _it shows just scribbles when_ You _open it_, how should it show anything else but scribbles when the Python interpreter opens it?

Comment: If you can't edit the script, you are basically out of luck. Python can parse your script using a different encoding, but only if you can edit the file to add a [specific comment to the top of the file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: Can you make a copy of the script and edit the copy? Are you sure that the encoding is ANSI (note that "ANSI" is a misnomer; it's more likely to be [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)). Can you contact the person who made the script for you?